# Why my render image looks so awful?

Tags: rendering, cycles-render-engine

I'm making a small animation and when i was rendering i notice this awful render and i don´t know why.
It's Render in Cycles, motion blur, 1920x1080 and at 1500 samples(even when i push the samples to 5000, still gets that image)

The only thing i have in composition is the denoiser.

I use Blender 2.83.

Can anyone help and thanks!

Here is a image:

[image]

Comment: It's the denoiser.

Comment: Yeah. the denoiser is set way too aggressive. A good render never really needs more than 500 samples at max in my experience. Even with photorealism. The denoiser is a magic tool that has been added to blender, but it isn't perfect. It will get rid of 99% of your noise. Don't try to make it get rid of 100% because that will result in these artifacts.